# List characteristics relevant to a noun

Tags: nlp, semantics, conceptnet

I try to list the (physical) characteristics relevant to a given noun, i.e., all the words (adjectives and nouns) that could describe this noun. For example:

```
road
```

... should return:

```
black, flat, tar, porous, long...
```

I've tried several unsatisfying approaches. For example, dictionaries should provide such words, but their definitions are too strict and too short. I also tried semantic networks such as ConceptNet (see [this link](https://conceptnet.io/c/en/road?rel=/r/HasProperty&limit=1000)). But to the best of my knowledge, the available resources (for my application) are scarce. I was never able to predict that a road is (usually) black.

Do you have any better idea/approach?

If this question is too naive, please excuse my poor knowledge of the field.

*Note: In my understanding, the problem is difficult because it deals with the "common sense": I get less Google results for "black road" (1.8m results) than "white road" (2.4m results) because nobody talks about the black roads (too obvious!). As a result, the training of the machine is biased.*